# Modbus communication

Tags: serial, communication, modbus

I try to read data from a device by raspberry 3 B+.

those two devices are connected via CH340G usb module (USB to Serial (TTL) adapter).
  Concerning the python code; here's:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient    
from pymodbus.register_read_message import ReadInputRegistersResponse  
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyUSB0', stopbits=1, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate='9600', timeout=0.3)  
connection=client.connect()
print(connection)  
value=client.read_input_registers(2301, 4, unit=0x01)  
print(value.registers)
```

And the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iot/Desktop/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyUSB0', stopbits=1, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate='9600', timeout=0.3)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymodbus/client/sync.py", line 442, in __init__
    if self.baudrate > 19200:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, specifically these two lines:

```
    if self.baudrate > 19200:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I take it that baudrate should be an integer number not a string... and I am not judging the library for not typechecking and/or trying to convert a well-formed string such as this one (well, I probably do).

Solution: do not use `baudrate='9600'` but `baudrate=9600`, the full line thus reads:

```
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyUSB0', stopbits=1, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate=9600, timeout=0.3)
```

Comment: @BrahimAssad please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Feel free to express your thanks by upvoting and/or accepting the answer in due time if it solves the issue.