# Serial communication error

Tags: serial, communication

Could someone help me to fix this error while trying to connect RPi 3 B+ to an inverter in order to read data via CH340G usb module, 
Below the used code :

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient  
from pymodbus.register_read_message import ReadInputRegistersResponse  
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyUSB0', stopbits=1, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate=9600, timeout=0.3)  
connection=client.connect()  
print(connection)  
value=client.read_input_registers(2301, 4, unit=0x01)  
print(value.registers)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/iot/Desktop/test.py", line 6, in value=client.read_input_registers(2301, 8, unit=0x01)                           File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymodbus/client/common.py", line 125, in read_input_registers – return self.execute(request)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymodbus/client/sync.py", line 105, in execute raise ConnectionException("Failed to connect[%s]" % (self.str())) pymodbus.exceptions.ConnectionException: Modbus Error: [Connection] Failed to connect[ModbusSerialClient(rtu baud[9600])]
```

Comment: There is no way to answer this question given the information provided.  You need to provide all relevant information up front.

Comment: hi, please specifie what kind of informations i can share with you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modbus communication](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98106/modbus-communication)

Comment: What is the difference to the question you asked 14 hours before?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it's an old recommendation to post it as new issue

Comment: It is not a duplicate as the error described there was solved by the answer given there. This is an issue that came up after that... thus a new question, which I suggested the OP to post it as such.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

*Setup*
Rpi3B+ config = CH340 USB/TTL adapter
UART connfig = /dev/ttyUSB0, 96008N1, timeout = 0.3

*Error* =
"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymodbus/client/sync.py", line 105
failed to connect

***Answer***

Rpi CH340 seems not able to connect to pymodus.  Suggest to first do Rpi/CH340 side loopback test.

***References***

[Pymodbus A Python Modbus Stack - 2018oct23](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pymodbus/dev/pymodbus.pdf)

[Modbus communication RpiSE Post - 2018may02](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98106/modbus-communication)